# How to remove Slack User Permanently

Tags: account-management, slack

I can't find a solution on how to do that, but there is a deactivate account but I want to remove the account permanently. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**On Year 2017**

This answer is provided by Slack itself, Admins or even Owner can't delete the users permanently because of this reason:

[image: Slack Note]

**Update: 2022**

According to Slack, the **profile information of the user can now be deleted**, the article is here:

> https://slack.com/help/articles/360000360443-Delete-profile-information-from-Slack

[image: Screenshot from Slack]

For full details, visit the link provided.

Answer (score 2):

We solved our need by changing the user's email address, this way we could create a new account using that same email address for a different person.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know what's the entire point of doing that if you just want to deactivate a person's account. And you can just add another user even if you only have the basic plan. Maybe it is just on your case, it actually depends. I don't want the new person's sees the old messages from the remove person. You know, privacy stuff.

Comment: @DPE It sounds like a bad practice.

Comment: @JoshuaDelaCruz do you wanted to delete it in order to re-use his address?

Comment: @arieljannai no, I just want to remove him entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you know if the person have been participating in any discussions and if the person did then only allow deactivate but if the person did not then allow delete of profile. That cant be very difficult.
How can the admin change someones email address, I don't see such an option.